# Python - What does the following mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What does the following mean in python?

```
var1 = [var2]
```

example:

```
self.locations = [sys.resources_location]
```

is var1 being declared as an array?

Comment: There are no arrays in core Python. `var1` becomes a list of one item `var2`.

Comment: @DYZ https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: @roganjosh Ok, what I meant was an array is not a built-in data type.

Comment: @DYZ fair enough. Can't say I've ever used the array so I don't actually know how useful it is :)

Comment: thank you for the explanation... btw. can anyone explain how sys.<argument> get's filled in typically? are these system variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**var1** is initialized as *list* with one element which is **var2**.

```
>>> var2 = 1
>>> var1 = [var2]
>>> type(var1)
<type 'list'>
```

You could learn more about list from this tutorial.

[Understanding Lists in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-lists-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

[The syntax `[x]`](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) creates a new list object with one element *x*.

You can try with the interactive shell, and use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#type) to find out more about the object:

```
>>> var2 = 42
>>> var1 = [var2]
>>> var1
[42]
>>> type(var1)
<type 'list'>
```

[Lists](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#list) are not [arrays](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/array.html); lists can be resized and contain elements of different types.